# I have pic16f877a pic dev board i want to know how to set the mplab to compile a program that can be fused on my pic microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, pic, mplab

I have a dev board but unfortunately i could not program my pic ic because that the compiler compiles the program succesfully but I am unable test on the dev board rather than the software  simulation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have to flash your PIC16F877A device rather that just simulate it on PC, you should run:

MPLAB IPE

[image]

then select family and device:

[image]

finally select you tool depending on what you have on your table,

as per list of all it can be:

[image]

and then press the <kbd>Program</kbd> button.

You may need to setup a minor number of additional options what suit your particular purposes.
For any reading and more understanding follow [this document](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/50002227A.pdf)

Comment: Thank you for your valuable comment

Comment: using pic downloader software i am trying to flash the hex file on the pic ic and the flashing is also done but it doesnt execute my program rather than that if i try to flash with a program which I have compiled with another version of mplab IDE in my old pc works perfectly